# How to get N unique random quantities without indefinite loop?

Tags: c, arrays, arc4random

I want to generate 5 random positions on a map.  I can only come up with the code below, which uses `while (1)` and `break`:

```
 int map[10][10];
 memset(map,0,sizeof(map));

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     while (1) {
         int x = RAND_FROM_TO(0, 10);
         int y = RAND_FROM_TO(0, 10);
         if (map[x][y]==0) {
             map[x][y]=1;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Is there any other way to do the same job without while(1), because I have been told the while(1) is very bad.

I just want to find a simple way to do it, so the efficiency of the generating random numbers is not under my consideration.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `while(1)`?  What happens if you remove the `while(1)` and the `break` statement?

Comment: @jeffamaphone Risk of writing a "1" where there is already one, I guess.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Because I want to generate different 5 pos. But I don't know how many times the random numbers can satisfy it. So I put while(1) there.

Comment: @Igor meet the needs of generating 5 different pos

Comment: Why do you think the `while(1)` is very bad? Maybe you should ask the people who told you it's bad what they would consider better.

Comment: To elaborate on @interjay, it is not clear whether `while (1)` is bad due to: a) bad syntax/style according to someone's preferenes or style guide (which could be fixed by e.g. switching to `for (;;)`), or b) bad performance (unnecessary jumps in the generated assembly leading to branch mispredictions, possibly avoidable using a smarter algorithm), or c) incorrect results (failing to terminate with a sufficiently pathological PRNG/seed combination). Depending on the answer to this, different approaches to "fix" the problem can be proposed.

Comment: @user4815162342 I didn't make my question clear as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a shuffle algorithm such as Fisher–Yates.  I would pose a modified (truncated) version as so:

1. Express your XY coordinates as a single number.
2. Construct a list of all coordinates.
3. Pick one at random, mark it.
4. Remove that coordinate from the list (swap it with the one at the end of the list, and treat the list as 1 element shorter)
5. repeat with the list that no longer contains the marked coordinate.

This way, rather than choosing 5 numbers from 0-99, you choose one 0-99, 0-98, ... 0-95, which guarantees that you can complete the task with exactly 5 choices.

EDIT: Upon further consideration, step 1 is not strictly necessary, and you could use this on a system with sparse coordinates if you did it that way.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
// Create an array of valid indexes for both x and y.
NSMutableArray *xCoords = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *yCoords = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    [xCoords addObject:@(i)];
    [yCoords addObject:@(i)];
}

int map[10][10];
memset(map, 0, sizeof(map));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    // Pick a random x coordinate from the valid x coordinate list.  
    int rand = RAND_FROM_TO(0, [xCoords count]);
    int x = [xCoords objectAtIndex:rand];

    // Now remove that coordinate so it cannot be picked again.
    [xCoords removeObjectAtIndex:rand];

    // Repeat for y.
    rand = RAND_FROM_TO(0, [yCoords count]);
    int y = [yCoords objectAtIndex:rand];
    [yCoords removeObjectAtIndex:rand];

    assert(map[x][y] == 0);
    map[x][y] = 1;
}
```

Note: I'm using `NSMutableArray` because you originally specified Objective-C as a tag.

Note 2: An array of valid indexes is not the most efficient representation.  Using [NSMutableIndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableIndexSet) instead is left as an exercise to the reader.  As is using basic C primitives if you don't / can't use `NSMutableArray`.

Note 3: This has a bug where if you pick, say, x = 3 the first time, no further choices will end up with x = 3, even though there will be valid choices where x = 3 but y is different.  Fixing that is also left as an exercise, but this does satisfy your requirements, on the surface.